# MUI MakeStyles not working as expected when passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, jss

I've been working on a range date picker made with **React** and **Material-ui**. I have an atom component (button) which gets some styles after dates some date values change.

Is not the best code but by now I only want to have the work done, the problem is that I wanted to do this with classes but only works as supposed when assigning styles to it, if i pass props to `useStyles(props)` it start to do weird things.

### Passing props to useStyles

1. Button with hover
2. Button clicked - start date
3. Range effect, hover on 16th
4. 16th clicked - end date
5. Hover on 14th
6. Weird behavior if start date selected but end date not selected

[image]

#### DatePickerButton.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import fcc from 'font-color-contrast';

import { colors } from 'UI/res/colors';
import { useStyles } from './styles';

const DatePickerDisplayButton = ({
  children,
  actualDate,
  displayDate,
  selectedDates: {
    start: startDate,
    end: endDate
  },
  focusedDate,
  type,
  index,
  onMouseEnter,
  onRangeChange,
  multiple,
  ...rest
}) => {
  // function expression that sets backgroundColor and color
  // depending on dates
  const getRangeBackgroundColor = () => {
    const color = fcc(colors.main.red.original);
    if (
      displayDate === startDate ||
      displayDate === endDate ||
      (displayDate === focusedDate && !endDate)
    ) {
      return { color, backgroundColor: colors.main.red.original };
    } else if (
      (displayDate > startDate && displayDate < endDate) ||
      (displayDate > startDate && displayDate < focusedDate && !endDate) ||
      (displayDate < startDate && displayDate > focusedDate && !endDate)
    ) {
      return { color, backgroundColor: colors.main.red.softer };
    }
    return null;
  };

  const classes = useStyles({
    index,
    multiple,
    // pass colors object to useStyles to get in props
    color: getRangeBackgroundColor()
  });

  return (
    <Button
      type="contained"
      onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter(displayDate)}
      onClick={onRangeChange(displayDate, type)}
      className={classes.calendarButton}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

#### Styles.js

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { colors } from 'UI/res/colors';

export const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  calendarButton: {
    width: 'calc(100% / 7)',
    minWidth: 'calc(100% / 7)',
    borderRadius: 0,
    margin: 0,
    borderTop: `1px solid ${colors.main.red.soft}`,
    borderLeft: `1px solid ${colors.main.red.soft}`,
    borderBottom: ({index, multiple}) => (index + 1 < multiple && index + 1 > multiple - 7) ? `1px solid ${colors.main.red.soft}` : null,
    borderRight: ({index}) => ((index + 1) % 7) === 0  ? `1px solid ${colors.main.red.soft}` : null,
    backgroundColor: ({color}) => color?.backgroundColor,
    color: ({color}) => color?.color
  }
}));
```

### With styles prop

This is the behavior needed, the only thing that changes is that I pass `getRangeBackgroundColor()` to my button `style` prop.

1. Button hover
2. Button clicked - start date selected
3. Finish date hover
4. Finish date selected - this one does't change if hovered when both dates are selected, no weird behavior if finish date haven't been selected

[image]

#### DatePickerButton.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import fcc from 'font-color-contrast';

import { colors } from 'UI/res/colors';
import { useStyles } from './styles';

const DatePickerDisplayButton = ({
  children,
  actualDate,
  displayDate,
  selectedDates: {
    start: startDate,
    end: endDate
  },
  focusedDate,
  type,
  index,
  onMouseEnter,
  onRangeChange,
  multiple,
  ...rest
}) => {
  
  const classes = useStyles({
    index,
    multiple
  });

  const getRangeBackgroundColor = () => {
    const color = fcc(colors.main.red.original);
    if (
      displayDate === startDate ||
      displayDate === endDate ||
      (displayDate === focusedDate && !endDate)
    ) {
      return { color, backgroundColor: colors.main.red.original };
    } else if (
      (displayDate > startDate && displayDate < endDate) ||
      (displayDate > startDate && displayDate < focusedDate && !endDate) ||
      (displayDate < startDate && displayDate > focusedDate && !endDate)
    ) {
      return { color, backgroundColor: colors.main.red.softer };
    }
    return null;
  };

  return (
    <Button
      type="contained"
      onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter(displayDate)}
      onClick={onRangeChange(displayDate, type)}
      className={classes.calendarButton}
      style={getRangeBackgroundColor()}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

#### Styles.js

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { colors } from 'UI/res/colors';

export const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  calendarButton: {
    width: 'calc(100% / 7)',
    minWidth: 'calc(100% / 7)',
    borderRadius: 0,
    margin: 0,
    borderTop: `1px solid ${colors.main.red.soft}`,
    borderLeft: `1px solid ${colors.main.red.soft}`,
    borderBottom: ({index, multiple}) => (index + 1 < multiple && index + 1 > multiple - 7) ? `1px solid ${colors.main.red.soft}` : null,
    borderRight: ({index}) => ((index + 1) % 7) === 0  ? `1px solid ${colors.main.red.soft}` : null
  }
}));
```

Comment: simply your codes with only the necessary props (e.g. index & multiple) and try again.